# How do I use nextUntil with a child selector?

Tags: jquery

Given this markup:

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="level1 selected">1</a></li>
    <li><a class="level2">2</a></li>
    <li><a class="level2">3</a></li>
    <li><a class="level2">4</a></li>
    <li><a class="level1">1</a></li>
    <li><a class="level2">5</a></li>
    <li><a class="level2">6</a></li>
    <li><a class="level2">7</a></li>
    <li><a class="level1">1</a></li>
</ul>
```

How do I select the `LI` tags whose childred have the class `level2` immediately following the `LI` tag whose child has the class `selected` ?

My initial code fails because I am not properly able to use the nextUntil() function.

```
// Selects the parent of the select A tag    
var selectedParent = $("ul li a.selected.level1").parents("li");

selectedParent.nextUntil("li a.level1").each(function () {
    $(this).children().addClass("on");
});
```

Comment: This would be much simpler if your level1/level2 class was on the `li` instead of the `a`.

Comment: Of course Blaze, but I have no control over the mark up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$lvl1 = $('a:not(.level2)').closest('li');
$lvl2 = $('a.selected').closest('li').nextUntil($lvl1);
```

or on a single line:

```
$lvl2 = $('a.selected').closest('li').nextUntil($('a:not(.level2)').closest('li'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/jKCrH/

Comment: Brilliant! Closest is my friend.

Comment: +1. Never know that nextUntil will accept a list of elements and stop when it encounter the first match.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using complex selectors (which will loop through too many objects inside jQuery), you can create a custom function for this. I think this will be more efficient. Try [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZRMp7/)

```
$.fn.nextTillList1 = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
        var $item = $(this).next("li");
        while($item.find(".level1").length <= 0) {
            $item.children().addClass("on");
            $item = $item.next("li");
        }
    });
};

// Selects the parent of the select A tag    
var selectedParent = $("ul li a.selected.level1").parents("li");

// Call custom function
selectedParent.nextTillList1();
```